# How to add border bottom lined with hr tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

So i want to make something looking like this:

[image]

but when i try it only look like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><span class="border-bottom border-primary">Daftar Kategori</span></h5>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :after selector with position relative and absolute , check this:

```css
h5{
     position:relative;
}
h5:after
{
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    border-bottom:4px solid #409bf7;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-bottom:21px;
}
hr{
    border-top:none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
}
```

```html
   <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title"><span class="border-bottom border-primary">Daftar Kategori</span></h5>
                        <hr>
                      
                         <h5 class="card-title"><span class="border-bottom border-primary">Daftar Kategori</span></h5>
                        <hr>
                      
    
                         <h5 class="card-title"><span class="border-bottom border-primary">Daftar Kategori</span></h5>
                        <hr>
                      
                         <h5 class="card-title"><span class="border-bottom border-primary">Daftar Kategori</span></h5>
                        <hr>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place an `:after` pseudo element on the `span` tag *so the bottom* ***"border"*** *only spans as far as the content*. Make the ***elements*** ***position*** ***relative*** and the ***pseudo tag's position absolute*** so you can control the position. ***left*** ***0*** and ***bottom*** ***-1.6rem***.

```css
.border-bottom {
  position: relative;
}

.border-bottom::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  background: #138ab5;
  bottom: -1.6rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">
        <span class="border-bottom border-primary">Daftar Kategori</span>
      </h5>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, it help me

Answer (score 0):

> You can use below styles for the hr tag

```
hr {
    background-color: #555;
    border: none;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

hr:before {
    background-color: #f90;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -2px;
    width: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
span.border-bottom.border-primary {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #0aa092;
    padding: 0 0 10px;
}
```